# php manual install; path to apxs2/mysql?

Tags: mysql, php, httpd

I'm building php from source..
just wondering which mysql path do I specify for --with-mysql= and --with-mysqli because whereis mysql returns:

## whereis mysql

mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz

Also, I installed httpd via yum (RHEL5) so I'm wondering what path to use for --with-apxs2=

## whereis httpd

httpd: /usr/sbin/httpd.event /usr/sbin/httpd /usr/sbin/httpd.worker /etc/httpd /usr/lib/httpd /usr/share/man/man8/httpd.8.gz

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you've installed mysql-devel and httpd-devel, you should be able to use:

```
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib64/mysql --with-mysql-include=/usr/include
```

If you're building for 32 bit, drop the `64` from `/usr/lib64`.

Answer (score 1):

If the path to `apxs2` (APache eXtenSion tool) is still a problem, you should install `apache2-dev`.

(on Ubuntu » `apache2-threaded-dev`)

Answer (score 0):

You will need all the -dev packages for the libraries you're compiling against. That meant mysqlclient-dev, httpd-devel amongst others.